# Sending the same data to N GPUs

Tags: cuda, pci-e

I have 4 GPUs hung off the same PCIe switch (PLX PEX 8747) on a Haswell based system. I want to send the same data to each GPU. Is it possible for the PCIe switch to replicate the data to N targets, rather than do N separate transfers? In effect is it possible to broadcast data to N GPUs over the PCIe bus?

I was wondering how SLI / Crosssfire handled such issues? I can imagine large amounts of data being identical identical for each GPU in a given scene being rendered. I remember reading somehwere that the old NVIDIA 890 Ultra SLI system included this broadcast mechanism in their switch for SLI.

http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/52280/NVIDIA_Broadcast_PWShort_TB.pdf

Is this possible with newer PCIe switches?

**Update**: It appears the PCIe standard supports multi-cast, as outlined by the answer below. I found some info on this at

www.pcisig.com/developers/main/training_materials/get_document?doc_id=31337695e3bc0310ea570c9df49e507b9d3eb4a5

Yes I specifically wanted a CUDA or OpenCL interface to transfer the data to N devices. Seems a shame the API doesn't support this yet.

Comment: There is no CUDA API to do this.  If your question is not about CUDA, please delete the CUDA tag.  Otherwise I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PCI-e SIG ratified a scheme for switch level multicast over PCI-e about 5 years ago, and it (I believe) is fully described in the PCI-e 3.0 standard. However, I don't believe any of the GPU/Acceleration vendors support multicast yet, and there certainly isn't any CUDA level API support for such a feature as of CUDA 5.5.

Comment: I'm pretty sure NVIDIA drivers use multicast under the hood in some circumstances (e.g multi-GPU rendering), however there is AFAIK no exposed API to take advantage of this provided by NVIDIA.  Upvoting, as this answer is correct and complete, in my opinion.