# Pytorch: Send same batch of data to multiple GPUs, and perform ops on each GPU individually

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, shared-data

I have the same dataloader to feed data to 4 models, each with a different hyperparameter loaded on a separate GPU. I want to reduce the bottleneck caused by data-loading, so I intend to load the same batch prepared by the dataloader on all GPUs for them to compute individually and perform a backprop step. I already cache data into RAM to avoid disk-bottlenecks when the dataloader in instantiated.

I am trying to:

1. Send/Broadcast the same batch of data to *N* GPUs. I guess this is possible only if we can sync/wait for all GPUs to finish ops for one batch, before we can proceed to the next one.
2. Bonus: Prefetching next batch as soon as one batch is ready (upto P batches) could help ensure continuous flow of data to the GPUs avoiding the wait.

I am not trying to achieve:

1. [Data Parallelism](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) - Split a large batch into *N* parts, and compute each part on one GPU
2. [Model Parallelism](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html) - Split computation of a large model (that won't fit on one GPU) into *N* (or less) parts and place each part on one GPU.

Similar questions:

1. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624102/using-multiple-gpus-outside-of-training-in-pytorch/55627889#55627889) is about making a Conv2D operation span across multiple GPUs
2. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498690/how-to-use-cuda-stream-in-pytorch) is about executing different GPU computations in parallel, but I don't know if my problem can be solved with [torch.cuda.Stream()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.stream)
3. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189133/how-to-do-random-search-for-hyperparameters-on-different-gpus-in-parallel) is about loading different models, but it does not deal with sharing the same batch.
4. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795486/sending-the-same-data-to-n-gpus) is exactly about what I'm asking, but it's CUDA/PCIe and from 7 years ago.

Update:

I found a very similar question [in Pytorch discuss](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/training-parallel-multiple-models/35238) where there is a small example at the end using forward prop using multiprocessing, but I'm wondering how to scale this approach to torch dataloaders.

Comment: If I understand you right, I think that instead of trying to run a different model on each GPU, the more standard approach would be to run the 4 models sequentially, each on 4 GPUs (here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-tune-hyperparameters) of hyperparameter tuning that is built into Azure:   I think the latter would be a lot easier to set up and might even be faster.